# Можно ли проверить в одной функции и потерю, и получение фокуса разных элементов?

Tags: android, kotlin

Данный код проверяет потерю фокуса текстовым полем и скрывает клавиатуру, если фокус теряет текстовое поле. Но получается некрасиво когда переход осуществляется тоже в текстовое поле - клавиатура скрывается и вновь открывает.
Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при переходе в другое текстовое поле клавиатура не скрывалась и не открывалась повторно. А оставалась открытой.

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val currentClickView: View? = currentFocus
        if (currentClickView is EditText) {
            currentClickView.clearFocus()
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentClickView.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
```

Если нужна какая-то проверка на получение фокуса текстовым полем, то как их объединить? что-то вроде:

```
viewItem.setOnClickListener { nextCurrent: View, hasFocus ->
    nextField = nextCurrent as EditText
    if(hasFocus)        
    ..............
}
```

Comment: можно попробовать показывать клавиатуру при фокусе, и тогда при переключении она будет показываться на любом поле для ввода

Comment: Она показывается при фокусе. Но есть задача скрывать клавиатуру при тапе вне текстового поля.